# How to send automated email every 24 hours using data stored in array - Android studio

Tags: java, android

I am creating a ClockIn Android app using java for employees and I would like the owner/manager to receive a daily email for when employees have clocked in and out. I am using an array to store this 'data' and plan on deleting all 'data' from the array when the email is sent. Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: perform these type of work on the server, you can send data to the server that employee had clocked by calling one API and sending the time of clocked In and out.so the email can be handled on the server

Answer (score 0):

As @sudeshregmi wrote, do it on the server side. Sending email in java does not require many libraries, `javax.mail` should be enough in Your case. Though, If You would like to send millions of emails I recommend looking into some cloud based solutions like aws.amazon.com/ses :)

For task scheduling You can use QUARTZ - https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/docs/quick-start-guide.adoc

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I would like to try doing it without a server for now as I do not expect many people to download the app. Is there any way to automatically repeat something every 24 hours?